# Mocha's before() function fails when used within CircleCI

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, circleci

I'm trying to test my JS code on CircleCI using Mocha, but getting the following error right at the start of testing:

```
Sample test suite
  1) "before all" hook: applyFixture

0 passing (77ms)
1 failing

1) Sample test suite "before all" hook: applyFixture:
 StatusCodeError: 404 - {"message":"Not Found"}
  at _stream_readable.js:943:16
```

**sample_test.js** file:

```
describe('Sample test suite', function() {

  before(function applyFixture() {
    var options = {
        uri: 'http://localhost:8000/sampleRoute',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        form: {dataset: 'test_dataset'},
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    };

    return rp(options)
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log('ready for testing!');
            } else {
                throw new Error('failed to load');
            }
        });
});
```

The following code works fine locally. It will also work on CircleCI if I include the code from the `before` block into the first test. `localhost:8000/sampleRoute` is also available before tests start.

Not sure how to troubleshoot this issue...

Comment: What do you expect to be served on port 8000? Are you sure CircleCI is launching your server, whatever that may be?

Comment: @ssube I should get a sample html page as a reply when trying to access `locahost:8000/sampleRoute`. I think CircleCI launching it properly. this is how I test (in `circle.yml` file) if the server is fully launched: `"while ! curl -sSf http://localhost:8000/sampleRoute &> /dev/null; do sleep 2; done"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Then issue was with the request's header. I had to specify authentication token in it in order to properly do POST requests. This is nothing to do with CircleCI.

Below is the proper `options` object that worked:

```
var options = {
    uri: 'http://localhost:8000/sampleRoute',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        authorization: 'authorizationToken'
    },
    form: {dataset: 'test_dataset'},
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
};
```